# unable to do redirect from login to dashboard

Tags: reactjs

Hello everyone i have wrote this code from the you tube...can any one help to betterment in this code and redirect or dashboard page..please...need to do sign up also...please help me to do these ... login to dashboard, logout to login , signup to dashboard
login api : http://127.0.0.10:8000/projectapi/signIn/ , 
signup api : http://127.0.0.10:8000/projectapi/registration/ 
this is the codesand box link: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-davinci-zsq6z?file=/src/components/login.js

login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import './login.scss';

export default class CollegeLogin extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            credentials: {
                username: '',
                password: ''
            }
        }
    }

    Login = (e) => {
        console.log(this.state.credentials)
        fetch("http://127.0.0.10:8000/projectapi/signIn/", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state.credentials)
        })
            .then(
                data => data.json()
            )
            .then(
                data => {
                    console.log(data)
                }
            ).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    ChangeFiled = (e) => {
        const cred = this.state.credentials;
        cred[e.target.name] = e.target.value
        this.setState({
            credentials: cred
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="College-login">
                <form>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Login</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <TextField label="Name" name="username" onChange={this.ChangeFiled} variant="outlined" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <TextField type="password" label="Password" name="password" onChange={this.ChangeFiled} variant="outlined" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className="buttons-login">
                        <Button className="login-btn" onClick={this.Login} variant="contained" color="primary">Login</Button>

                        <NavLink exact to="/sign-up/college-registration/">
                            <Button className="register-btn" color="primary">Register</Button>
                        </NavLink>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default class SamplePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            redirect: false
        }
    }

    logout() {
        console.log('You have beeb logout')
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sample" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <div style={{ position: 'absolute', right: '25px' }}>
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.logout}>
                        Logont
                   </Button>
                </div>
                <h3>Sample</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

signup.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import './sign-up.scss';

export default class CollegeSignUp extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            username: '',
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }

    }
    ChangeFiled = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    register = (e) => {
        console.log(this.state.name, " " + this.state.username, " " + this.state.email, " " + this.state.password)


    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="college-sign-up">
                <h3>Sign Up</h3>
                <div>
                    <TextField label="Name" name="name" onChange={this.ChangeFiled} variant="outlined" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <TextField label="UserName" name="username" onChange={this.ChangeFiled} variant="outlined" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <TextField type="email" label="Email" name="email" onChange={this.ChangeFiled} variant="outlined" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <TextField type="password" label="Password" name="password" onChange={this.ChangeFiled} variant="outlined" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div className="buttons-registration"> <NavLink exact to="/">
                    <Button className="college-registartion-btn" color="primary">Login</Button>
                </NavLink>
                    <Button className="collge-registartion-login-btn" onClick={this.register} variant="contained" color="primary">Register</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) prop from the route props being provided by each Route. `history.replace` is the equivalent of a redirect.

```
this.props.history.replace(...)
```

login.js - In the success branch of the promise chain

```
Login = e => {
  console.log(this.state.credentials);
  fetch("http://127.0.0.10:8000/projectapi/signIn/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.credentials)
  })
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.props.history.replace("/dashboard");
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

*Note: I initially placed it in a `finally` block since the codesnadbox likely doesn't have your auth logic (request times out @~45s) so I could navigate*

dashboard.js - In the logout function. Also need to bind `this` of the component to the function in order to be able to access the props. Here I used an arrow function.

```
logout = () => {
  console.log("You have beeb logout");
  this.props.history.replace("/");
};
```

signup.js - At the end of the register function

```
register = e => {
  this.props.history.replace("/dashboard");
};
```

[image: Edit strange-shtern-2s2vk]

Comment: hi drew..i want block user in the login page if the user given wrong credentials. sample credentials : username : Login , Password : Login

Comment: @ManuPanduu Right, so *only* place the `history.replace` in the happy path, i.e. the `then` block where you get the response. I just updated the sandbox to do this.

Comment: @ManuPanduu I don't think I quite understand your question, but this is all happening in the front end.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-butterfly-od1d0?file=/src/components/signup.js    i am unable to do logout..its saying Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Comment: @ManuPanduu Oh yeah, you need to either bind `this` to it in the constructor, or use an arrow function to get `this` of the component bound to the function.

Comment: can you do that and replace the code in sandbox...please

Comment: @ManuPanduu I had already done that in the sandbox in order to get it working. Just updated answer.

Comment: @drewreese..can we restrict the landing page from the user , if user given wrong credentials....from the front end...please help me...i can see in the response in the network like these "Unable to log in with provided credentials."

Comment: hi drew reese....i have asked another question in stackover flow....can you please see and answer....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832761/how-to-post-check-box-value-and-checked-status