# how to post check box value and checked status

Tags: reactjs

i am getting checkbox values , checked status, checkbox label, checkbox courseid. from the server using of axios method.....now i want to send back checked of checkbox value and checked status..to back end using axios method...
can any one help on these...[image: console of resposne].

i am unable to do and print in console of response...please any one help

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
    import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
    import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
    import { List, ListItem } from '@material-ui/core';
    import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
    import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
    import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
    import Axios from 'axios'

    class TwelvethCollegeCourses extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                checkboxes: [],
            }
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            Axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkboxapi/checkbox/')
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({ checkboxes: response.data })
                    console.log(response.data)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
        ChangeCheckBox = (e) => {
            // onchange code checkbox
        };
        checkBoxSubmit = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            Axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkboxapi/user/')
                .then(response => {
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        };
        render() {
            const { checkboxes } = this.state
            return (
                <div>
                    <Container-Fluid>
                        <Row className="college-courses-row">
                            <Col sm={4} className="courses-box-college-courses-selected">
                                <div className="main-boxes">
                                    <div className="course-collge-regis-index-boxes">
                                        <div className="scrolling-data check-boxex-list">
                                            <form>
                                                <FormGroup aria-label="position" row>
                                                    <List className="courses-college-regis">
                                                        {checkboxes.map((checkbox, key) => (
                                                            <ListItem button key={key}>
                                                                <FormControlLabel
                                                                    label={checkbox.CourseLabel}
                                                                    type="checkbox"
                                                                    id={checkbox.CourseId}
                                                                    name="intermediatecourse"
                                                                    value={checkbox.CourseValue}
                                                                    control={<Checkbox color="primary" />}
                                                                    onChange={this.ChangeCheckBox}
                                                                    checked={checkbox.checked}
                                                                />
                                                            </ListItem>
                                                        ))}
                                                    </List>
                                                </FormGroup>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={8}>
                                <div className="total-number-courses-save-box ">
                                    <Button type="submit" onClick={this.checkBoxSubmit}>Save</Button>

                                </div>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Container-Fluid>
                </div >
            )
        }
    }

    export default TwelvethCollegeCourses;
```

Comment: What is the error? Use `Axios.post()` to send post request.

Comment: sorry, i did a mistake....can you tell me how to post that checkbox value and checked status..please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the form submit event to target the checkbox name, which yields a list of HTMLElement nodes. Convert them to an array and map into a list of key-value pairs using the input `id` and `checked` properties. `Object.fromEntries` converts this array into an Object.

The question now is, what format does your data need to be in for the POST request?

```
checkBoxSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const checkedValues = Array.from(e.target.intermediatecourse).map(el => [
    el.id,
    el.checked
  ]);

  // now have object of id-checked key-value pairs
  // filter/format accordingly for POST request endpoint needs
  // JSON.stringify and place in body of request

  Axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkboxapi/user/')
    .then(response => {
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
};
```

[image: Edit form submit get checkbox values]

**EDIT**

I see you've also attached the `checkBoxSubmit` callback to the button's onClick handler versus the form's onSubmit handler. This means the handler is receiving a click event from the button instead of a submit event from the form.

```
<Button type="submit" onClick={this.checkBoxSubmit}>Save</Button>
```

Should move handler to form

```
<form onSubmit={this.checkBoxSubmit}>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer drew...can we chat about this..i have sent invitation....i have some doubts

Comment: hi drew... i have asked another question stack over flow..please find it ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863949/functional-component-to-class-component