# functional component to class component

Tags: reactjs

hi i want use dialog box in my project...but i got that diaog box with functional component...can any one to convert into class based component and give me the answer please...
this code has been taken form the material ui....i am not much familar with functional component...
can any one help on these...please

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

export default function ScrollDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [scroll, setScroll] = React.useState('paper');

  const handleClickOpen = (scrollType) => () => {
    setOpen(true);
    setScroll(scrollType);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const descriptionElementRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      const { current: descriptionElement } = descriptionElementRef;
      if (descriptionElement !== null) {
        descriptionElement.focus();
      }
    }
  }, [open]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleClickOpen('paper')}>scroll=paper</Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClickOpen('body')}>scroll=body</Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        scroll={scroll}
        aria-labelledby="scroll-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="scroll-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="scroll-dialog-title">Subscribe</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent dividers={scroll === 'paper'}>
          <DialogContentText
            id="scroll-dialog-description"
            ref={descriptionElementRef}
            tabIndex={-1}
          >
            {[...new Array(50)]
              .map(
                () => `Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.
Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.`,
              )
              .join('\n')}
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Subscribe
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I suggest you study about functional component concepts, since it's very easy to understand and future is functional component since, nobody wants to write class components now a days.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service

Comment: okay okay...i wont ask again like these..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *should* be able to use a functional component regardless of really understanding how they work, but converting functional components is fairly trivial if you understand react state/props/lifecycle.

Basic steps:

1. Convert all state hooks to single state object and update all state update functions to now use `this.setState` with the correct state to be merged.
2. Convert effect hooks to appropriate lifecycle function (usually `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and/or `componentWillUnmount`.
3. Convert ref hook to regular react.createRef`.
4. Convert all callback and utility functions to be instance functions (remove `const`).
5. Move previous return into `render` lifecycle function
6. Update all state/prop, and callback and utility functions to correctly access `this` of the component, either for function invocation or state/prop access.

Class-based component

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";

export default class ScrollDialog extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    scroll: "paper"
  };

  handleClickOpen = scrollType => () => {
    this.setState({
      open: true,
      scroll: scrollType
    });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  descriptionElementRef = createRef();

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.open) {
      const { current: descriptionElement } = this.descriptionElementRef;
      if (descriptionElement !== null) {
        descriptionElement.focus();
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { open, scroll } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClickOpen("paper")}>scroll=paper</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClickOpen("body")}>scroll=body</Button>
        <Dialog
          open={open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          scroll={scroll}
          aria-labelledby="scroll-dialog-title"
          aria-describedby="scroll-dialog-description"
        >
          <DialogTitle id="scroll-dialog-title">Subscribe</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent dividers={scroll === "paper"}>
            <DialogContentText
              id="scroll-dialog-description"
              ref={this.descriptionElementRef}
              tabIndex={-1}
            >
              {[...new Array(50)]
                .map(
                  () => `Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
  Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.
  Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
  Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.`
                )
                .join("\n")}
            </DialogContentText>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
              Subscribe
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit snowy-platform-t1xox]

Comment: hello drew reese....i do not no how to create a chat room in stack over flow....stack over flow  not accepting to ask questions....if your free can create chat room..i have question  to ask not about the code.......mobile browser and mobile application view

Comment: hello..drew....i have asked anoher question in stackover flow...can you see that one answer.....please..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63381942/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-itself-in-pr